# How to Show ONLY Products Created within a Week on Homepage Category Block

Tags: magento2, frontend, html

```
<div class="product-tab-carousel">{{widget type="Codazon\ProductFilter\Block\Product\ProductsList" display_type="all_products" products_count="16" order_by="sold_count DESC" show="thumb,name,sku,description,review,price,addtocart,addto" thumb_width="260" thumb_height="260" filter_template="custom" custom_template="product/widget/content/infinitescroll_grid_custom.phtml" show_slider="1" slider_item="24" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`category_ids`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:`987`^]^]" cache_lifetime="600"}}</div>
```

I'm trying to show products created within a week on my homepage category block but is there any way to make it happen with markup language or else?

Comment: You can create a block with custom product collection with filter by daterange and call that in home page.